# Protractor W3C capability

Tags: protractor, desiredcapabilities, selenoid, webdriver-w3c-spec

I am using `Protractor` with `Selenoid`. I need to use the dockerized Windows images so that I can test Internet Explorer and Edge from Linux boxes.

I was able to make it work from curl by running:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session -d '{"capabilities":{"browserName":"MicrosoftEdge","count":1,"alwaysMatch":{"browserName":"MicrosoftEdge","selenoid:options":{"enableVNC":true,"enableVideo":false,"enableLog":true,"logName":"edge-18.0.log"}}}}'
```

My protractor config looks like:

```
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: "MicrosoftEdge",
      "alwaysMatch": {
        browserName: "MicrosoftEdge",
        "selenoid:options": {
          enableVNC: true,
          enableVideo: false,
          enableLog: true,
          logName: "edge-18.0.log"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

But `protractor` send it over the `selenoid` server like this:

```
{
    "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
        "count": 1,
        "alwaysMatch": {
            "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
            "selenoid:options": {
                "enableVNC": true,
                "enableVideo": false,
                "enableLog": true,
                "logName": "edge-18.0.log"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that `desiredCapabilities` should just be 'capabilities`. I have been looking everywhere trying to find out where is that created so that I can created some sort of flag to be able to switch it.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that only Protractor 6.0.0 fully supports w3c. Are you using latest version?

Comment: Right on the money. Thank you @vania-pooh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Protractor `6.0` solve my issue, but broke all my tests.

I was able to keep using `5.4.1` by patching the selenium-webdriver package. Looking at the way Protractor `6` did it, I did it to Protractor `5.4.1`:

I edited the file located at `node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js` and added the following:

```
// Capability names that are defined in the W3C spec.
const W3C_CAPABILITY_NAMES = new Set([
    'acceptInsecureCerts',
    'browserName',
    'browserVersion',
    'platformName',
    'pageLoadStrategy',
    'proxy',
    'setWindowRect',
    'timeouts',
    'unhandledPromptBehavior',
]);
```

Then in the same file I modify the `static createSession(executor, capabilities, opt_flow, opt_onQuit)` method to add the following:

```
    let W3CCaps = new Capabilities(capabilities);
    for (let k of W3CCaps.keys()) {
      // Any key containing a colon is a vendor-prefixed capability.
      if (!(W3C_CAPABILITY_NAMES.has(k) || k.indexOf(':') >= 0)) {
        W3CCaps.delete(k);
      }
    }

    cmd.setParameter('capabilities', W3CCaps);
```

After all those changes the request getting to Selenoid is like this:

```
{
    "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
        "version": "18.0",
        "enableVNC": true,
        "enableVideo": false,
        "count": 1
    },
    "capabilities": {
        "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge"
    }
}
```

And my Protractor 5 config looks like this:

```
  multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
    version: '18.0',
    enableVNC: true,
    enableVideo: false
  }]
```

**Note:**

So that I don't have to worry about refresh installs or updates I use the package `patch-package` (https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) to create a patch that is applied when any of those events happen. Here is a great video explaining how to use that package https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBPcVGr6XPk

Comment: Keep in mind that protractor 6.0 is still BETA and not yet stable